# Base mesh protrudes through armor

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, weight-painting, pose-mode

I am trying to position my character to push/break the pillars apart. However, when I try to put his arms into position, the base mesh protrudes through his armor (Bandos chestplate).

I have tried to reduce the weight paint around his spine and shoulder areas but it leaves my mesh jagged and out of proportion. What is the best approach to this?

I've attached my file and screenshots below. Many thanks.

https://pasteall.org/blend/6dde8dba444c40a78a88d05083cdeb82

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply correct it in *Weight Paint* mode (select the *Blend > Subtract* mode):

[image]

Comment: When I used weight paint, I kept clicking the left mouse button, that's why my mesh was going out of proportion. I held down the left mouse button while going over the mesh and that solved my problem. Thank you moonboots.